# SQL statement error when using select and update query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use a standard query which I got to work but now I need it to update a field in the table.

The below is my SQL but I keep getting the error: Syntax error in query expression

```
'FuelMaster.FleetNo = qryEndOdo.FleetNo
AND FuelMaster.FillOdo = qryEndOdo.FillOdo
AND FuelMaster.Date >= qryEndOdo.Date.
```

Below is my SQL:

```
UPDATE FuelMaster
SET FuelMaster.EndOdo = ((SELECT FuelMaster.ID, FuelMaster.Date, FuelMaster.FleetNo, FuelMaster.FillOdo, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.FillOdo
FROM FuelMaster AS Dupe
WHERE Dupe.FleetNo = FuelMaster.FleetNo
AND Dupe.Date >= FuelMaster.Date
AND Dupe.FillOdo > FuelMaster.FillOdo
ORDER BY Dupe.Date ASC) AS EndOdo
FROM FuelMaster))
WHERE EXISTS (FuelMaster.FleetNo = qryEndOdo.FleetNo
AND FuelMaster.FillOdo = qryEndOdo.FillOdo
AND FuelMaster.Date >= qryEndOdo.Date);
```

Comment: First of all, `EXISTS` always requires a select statement, you can think of it as "Does this statement returns any rows?".  Second, it seems you want to save in the EndOdo COLUMN the result of a SUBQUERY which returns MULTIPLE COLUMNS and (potentially) MULTIPLE ROWS.

Comment: So what would be the best way around this? And yes it does return multiple rows

Comment: what is the primary key / unique identifier for the FuelMaster table? if you can write a standalone  query to determinate the NewValue you can wrtie something like: `UPDATE FM SET FM.EndOdo = SQ.NewValue FROM FuelMaster FM INNER JOIN (SELECT Dupe.$PRIMARY_KEY$, NewValue FROM FuelMater Dupe ...) SQ ON FM.$PRIMARY_KEY$ = SQ.$PRIMARY_KEY$ WHERE FM.EndOdo <> SQ.NewValue`, where the $PRIMARY_KEY$ stands for the tables's identity

Comment: I can't write the SUBQUERY's logic atm, because I didn't catch the logic behind the NewValue and don't have enough information about the FuelMaster tables structure

Comment: Is there a way to enter this as an expression in the main table and set that field as a calculated field and use the expression to find the values?

Comment: Okay basically I have managed to write the SQL to get calculate the values and show this in the EndOdo column in the subform.
I have used the main recording table for the query to achieve this.

Comment: SQL below:
SELECT FuelMaster.ID, FuelMaster.Date, FuelMaster.FleetNo, FuelMaster.FillOdo, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.FillOdo
FROM FuelMaster AS Dupe
WHERE Dupe.FleetNo = FuelMaster.FleetNo
AND Dupe.Date >= FuelMaster.Date
AND Dupe.FillOdo > FuelMaster.FillOdo
ORDER BY Dupe.Date ASC) AS EndOdo, FuelMaster.Driver, FuelMaster.Registration, FuelMaster.Company, FuelMaster.Category, FuelMaster.FuelAcc, FuelMaster.FuelRef,

Comment: FuelMaster.FuelRefNo, FuelMaster.Time, FuelMaster.Depot, FuelMaster.Litres, FuelMaster.Cost, FuelMaster.[Cost/L], FuelMaster.TripKm, FuelMaster.Unit, FuelMaster.[ActualL/100], FuelMaster.[TargetL/100], FuelMaster.[DiffL/100], FuelMaster.[ActualC/100], FuelMaster.[TargetC/Km], FuelMaster.[DiffC/Km]
FROM FuelMaster;

Comment: This query is to show the EndOdo on the subform when entering in a new fuel record.

What I now need is when I put a new FillOdo value in on the main form I need the query to do its thing and calculate the EndOdo for the previous fill but need the main recording table to get these EndOdo readings as well.

Does this make sense at all?

I know I need to use an update query but I need to combine the select query from above into a update query and unfortunately have no idea how to do this without getting errors.

Comment: So why do you want to update existing records, which essentially duplicates a value? To   improve query performance? Edit question to show sample data as text table.

Comment: Date is a reserved word. Advise not to use reserved words as object names. FillDate would be better.

Comment: And no, cannot calculate in table Calculated type field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested UPDATE and get error "Operation must use an updatable query". Don't think can get what you want with single query. Options:

1. save correlated query object

```
SELECT ID, Nz((SELECT TOP 1 FillOdo FROM FuelMaster AS DUP 
    WHERE DUP.FleetNo=FuelMaster.FleetNo AND Dup.FillDate<FuelMaster.FillDate 
    ORDER BY FillDate DESC),0) AS BeginOdo
FROM FuelMaster;
```

and use it as source for DLookup() to update a field named BeginOdo (instead of EndOdo)

```
UPDATE FuelMaster SET FuelMaster.BeginOdo = DLookUp("BeginOdo","Query1","ID=" & [ID]);
```

2. populate a temp table with correlated query records and use table as source for UPDATE
3. use VBA and loop recordset object
4. don't update table, pull previous odometer reading via query when needed - already have the query to accomplish that

Comment: thank you so much, I really appreciate it

Comment: Thank you, figured that unfortunately so managed to achieve it using your method thanks again